# Use Ajax parameter in php fetch will not work

Tags: php, sql, ajax, fetch

I just use to send a parameter (with ajax) to a php and use this sended parameter as value in the SQL fetch (in where statement).

This is my code:
Ajax/HTML:

```
      <select id='overallval'>
       <option value='81'>81</option>
       <option value='83'>83</option>
       <option value='88'>88</option>
     </select>

      $('#overallval').change(function(){
    table.draw();
  });

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( 
    {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "type": "POST",
        "ajax": {
            "url": 'https://WEBSERVER.com/server_processing.php',
            'data': function(data){
              // Read values
              var overall = $('#overallval').val();
              // Append to data
              data.overallpara = overall;
            }
        },
        "columnDefs": [...]
```

My PHP:

```
$where = "overall > '.$_POST['overallpara'].'";
echo json_encode(SSP::complex( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns,null, $where ));
```

If I just use for example

```
$where = "overall > 88";
```

Everything works fine.. but my above posted method to use the POST-var does not fetch any data.
I used Firefox to debug the parameters that gets sended by the htm-file and a "overallpara" with value "88" gets sended.

So what could be the problem?

Comment: `$where = "overall > {$_POST['overallpara']}";`

Comment: Or `$where = "overall > '".$_POST['overallpara']."'";`

Comment: Nicks solution gave me a "ataTables warning: table id=example - An SQL error occurred: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use" error

Comment: The one from Barmar just give me all records (also overall lower then any value you can choose)

Comment: Looks like you are creating an sql injection vulnerability, you need to sanitize,
 your value somehow, so maybe intval() would be what you need.
`$where = "overall > ".intval($_POST['overallpara']);`

Comment: Misorude thanks for that link. I've searched the internet for example and no one of them was working.. that confused me. I've tried nearly any combination.

Comment: Maybe you should first of all check whether your script actually received the value you think it did in `$_POST['overallpara']` …?

Comment: … which it probably didn’t, because you are executing that part inside `$(document).ready`, at which point the user probably has not even selected any of these options yet. The request you are making there, probably needs to happen in combination with `$('#overallval').change` to begin with …?

Comment: Thats a good hint. Ajax sends overallpara:81 but a `echo $where` shows me:`overall > 0`

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code is wrong `$where = "overall > '.$_POST['overallpara'].'";`

```
//Replace it with my code
$where = "overall > {$_POST['overallpara']}";
```

Comment: Thanks but this gave me the following exception:

`DataTables warning: table id=example - An SQL error occurred: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY playerid ASC
    LIMIT 0, 10' at line 4`

Answer (score 0):

I had to use $_REQUEST instead of $_POST in my php script. Now it works. Could anyone explain me why I need it? It was just a test so idk why I have to use it. :(